# How do I make a text box appear after selecting an option from a drop-down menu in SuiteScript?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, netsuite, suitescript

I am new to SuiteScript. Right now I am trying to make a form using a Suitelet. In this form I want to add logic to the Suitelet where if a user selects an option from a dropdown menu, then that option will make a textbox appear for the user to enter more details in that selection. Here is my code so far.

```
function suitelet(request, response) {

    //create form
    var form = nlapiCreateForm('Form Title');

    var a = 'a';
    var b = 'b';
    var other = 'Other';

    // adds dropdown menu
    var selectField = form.addField('custpage_menu', 'select', 'Random Dropdown Menu');
    selectField.addSelectOption('', '', false);
    selectField.addSelectOption(a, a, false);
    selectField.addSelectOption(b, b, false);
    selectField.addSelectOption(other, other, false);
    selectField.setMandatory(true);

    //render a button for the user to submit form
    form.addSubmitButton('Submit');

    //load form
    response.writePage(form);
}
```

I would like the text box to appear when the user selects the option "Other". So in this case, the code line `selectField.addSelectOption(other, other, false);` represents the selection option labeled as "Other". This selection happens before the user clicks the submit button, so I don't think any POST requests are happening at this point.

I am not exactly sure what kind of event fires whenever a user selects an option from a dropdown menu. If I can capture that event through my code, then my hope is that I should be able to make a text box appear based on the selection.

EDIT: I forgot to mention one thing. I am not working with records at all. This is just a pure form that is generated by a Suitelet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to associate a client script to your Suitelet. Then use a field change function to capture the event when the user select an option from your dropdown. You must hide the text box when you create it on the suitelet and then play with the field.isDisplay property in your client like this:

```
function fieldChanged(){ 
   if (context.fieldId == 'custpage_menu') {
      var boxField = context.currentRecord.getField('custpage_your_text_box_id');
      if(other was selected){
          boxField.isDisplay = true;
      } else {
          boxField.isDisplay = false;
      }
   } 
}
```

I am adding here the code in 1.0, I though it was in 2.0 at the beginning, the approach is the same, I will leave the 2.0 version in case it is useful for someone else:

```
function clientFieldChanged(type, name, linenum){
   if(name == 'custpage_menu') {
      var optionSelected = nlapiGetFieldValue('custpage_menu');
      if(other was selected){
         nlapiGetField('custpage_your_text_box_id').setDisplayType('normal');
      } else{
         nlapiGetField('custpage_your_text_box_id').setDisplayType('hidden');
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I forgot to mention that my code is just a form generated by a Suitelet, so I am not dealing with records.

Comment: Thomas93, I think that you probably do not know that you are able to use currentRecord in a client script associated to a suitelet script. This solution works, I have tested it. You do not need to deploy this client script to any record, you just need to add this line: form.clientScriptFileId = 'client_script_file_id'.

Comment: I do know that I can use an undeployed client script associated with a suitelet. But if that Suitelet doesn't work on any records, then I don't understand how currentRecord can be still be used in this context. The form that the Suitelet generates is not a record that can be saved to the Netsuite database. Also, I am coding in SuiteScript 1.0. I am not sure if 2.0 is any different.

Comment: thomas93, see above my updated reply. I am not sure what you mean with a record that cannot be saved. if you have a suitelet and it creates a form that is displayed in the UI and then you create a simple file with my code above in the file cabinet and then associated it to the suitelet, the code will hide and display the desired field.

Comment: Your 1.0 code solved my problem, thanks. I think when I saw currentRecord in your 2.0 code, I just instantly thought that you were referring to a Netsuite record. Like an employee record for example. But the 1.0 code clarified everything for me, so thanks.

Comment: Happy to help. You should try as a test my code in 2.0 as well. the currentRecord is the way you get the form and fields in 2.0 when you are in a client script, even if you are using a suitelet and not a record itself.

Answer (score 1):

Using a client Script you can hide and show the field in Suitelet form. So Create a field and hide that field using Client script or suitelet only (setdisplaytype).

In client script you can define field change function and if the option is others then show the the text field.

I am adding some reference code snippets for functions

For setting a client script in suitelet

```
form.clientScriptFileId = '264221';
```

For Field change in Client side

```
  /*Field Change event*/
               function fieldChanged(scriptContext) {
                    var records = scriptContext.currentRecord;
                    if (scriptContext.fieldId == "datefiltertype") {
                        var type = records.getValue({
                            fieldId: 'datefiltertype'
                        });

                        if (type == "NOTWITHIN" || type == "WITHIN") {
                            jQuery("#fromdate_fs_lbl_uir_label").html("To");
                            jQuery("#todate_fs_lbl_uir_label").html("From");
                            jQuery("#fromdate_fs_lbl_uir_label").show();
                            jQuery("#fromdate").show()
                        } else {
                            jQuery("#fromdate").val("");
                            jQuery("#fromdate_fs_lbl_uir_label").hide();
                            jQuery("#fromdate").hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
```